# How to run a script published as webapp as user?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have published a script as webapp (Execute the app as:user accessing the app, Who has access to the app: anyone) and I am calling the script from GAE by adding the access token to the request (Authentication: Bearer XXXXX)

```
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(new URL(url), HTTPMethod.GET);
request.getFetchOptions().setDeadline(60d);
String accessToken = Ultradox.refreshAccessToken(account);
// Adding access token to request");
request.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken));
HTTPResponse response = urlFetch.fetch(request);
String result = new String(response.getContent(), "UTF-8");
```

I am getting an unauthenticated error screen.

Comment: Please add some code... It will help us understand what you wish to do.

Answer (score 0):

If it was working before, and is now broken, and you didn't make any changes, I'd report the issue to Google:

[google-apps-script-issues](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/)

The wording of your question is misleading.  You already know how to do what you are doing, or else it wouldn't have worked in the past.  Stack Overflow isn't for checking in to see if Google has an issue or not.